# rubyの正規表現で/nを含まずhtmlタグを削除する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

#### 発生しているエラー

`rails c` でスクリプトを流す場合、helpers.strip_tagsが使えない。
gsubと正規表現でhtmlタグを取り除こうとすると ”/n” の改行コードも含まれてしまう

#### 期待する動作

以下の真ん中にある `/n` を含めずにhtmlタグを消したい

```
<p>山田 /n 太郎</p>
```

#### エラーの内容

こちらの正規表現を記述するとhtmlタグ（pタグ）を除去できるが、”/n”もまとめて除去されてしまう。

```
User.first.User_name.gsub(/<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/, "")
```

#### 試したこと

htmlタグを指定する前に”/n”を除く記述を試した。
うまく除去ができない。

```
User.first.User_name.gsub(^(?!.*/n).$/<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/, "")
```

---

条件としては

- タグを除去する
- /nの改行コードは除く

正規表現がうまくできず、困ってます。
知見のある方お手数ですがご教授頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: `/n` と書かれている部分は `\n` の間違いでしょうか？

Comment: /nで間違いないかと思います！

Answer (score 0):

実は、

> rails c でスクリプトを流す場合、helpers.strip_tagsが使えない。

ということはなくて、コンソール内部で

```rb
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
```

とすると、`strip_tags`メソッドが呼べるようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
試してみます